# Is there a way to map python nose2 to coverage plugin which is installed in custom location?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, coverage.py, nose2

I have installed nose2 with the following command:

```
pip3 install nose2
```

And I have installed the coverage in the custom path with the following command:

```
pip3 install --target=/tmp/coverage_pkg coverage
```

I want to execute the test cases and generate the coverage report. Is there a way to map my coverage plugin installed in custom path to the nose2?

I tried to execute the below command:

```
nose2 --with-coverage
```

I got the following output:

```
Warning: you need to install "coverage_plugin" extra requirements to use this plugin. e.g. `pip install nose2[coverage_plugin]`

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

I want to generate the coverage report by using the coverage package installed in custom path.

Can someone please explain if I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using the following command:

```
cd <custom location where packages are installed>

python3 -m nose2  --with-coverage -s "path_to_source_dir" --coverage "path_to_source_dir"
```

You need to stay in the location where nose2 and coverage in installed(Custom dir/ Eg: /tmp/coverage_pkg).

For more configuration and generating junit report and coverage report we can use the `unittest.cfg` file and `.coveragerc` for controlling coverage report and unit testing.

Sample `unittest.cfg`:

```
[unittest]
plugins = nose2.plugins.junitxml
start-dir = 
code-directories = 
test-file-pattern = *_test.py
test-method-prefix = t

[junit-xml]
always-on = True
keep_restricted = False
path = nose2-junit.xml
test_fullname = False

[coverage]
always-on = True
coverage = 
coverage-config = .coveragerc
coverage-report = term-missing
                  xml
```

Sample `.coveragerc`:

```
[run]
branch = True
[xml]
output =coverage.xml
[report]
show_missing = True
omit=
    /test/*
    /poc1.py
    /bin/__init__.py
```

Use the below command for using config file and generate unittest report and coverage report.

```
python3 -m nose2 --config "<path to config file>/unittest.cfg"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message includes the exact command you need:

```
pip install nose2[coverage_plugin]
```

Comment: I have already installed coverage in this dir /tmp/coverage_pkg, as mentioned above, I want to use the coverage package installed here in custom location. How can I map this?

Comment: Can you say more about why you are installing coverage in a different place than the rest of your tools?

Comment: I'm trying to configure this in jenkins node. I have installed coverage in default path using "pip3 install coverage". But when i execute "coverage --version" its giving error:
`# coverage --version`

`cat: /ade_info.vmd: No such file or directory
/usr/local/packages/dbtest/CodeCoverage/src/cli/coverage/bin/coverage_3.1: line 21: [: =: unary operator expected
Initializing coverage command line 3.1
`I think there is a symlink created by someone/ I don't know who is using this. I donot want to disturb the flow on server, So I have installed coverage in custom path and try to configure it.